# Box2d coordinate system vs Pixels retina display

Tags: cocos2d-iphone, box2d, retina-display

I am feeling difficult in understanding box2d coordinate system vs pixels or points in cocos2d.I am using retina display too.
i tried with PTM_RATIO 32 and 30 also.
But,I think box2d is not linear with pixels.Could you suggest me how to sync them.

I need to design a game that need to use pixels exactly.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

PTM_RATIO stands for Pixel to Meter Ratio, so this number is just scaling what Box2D thinks is a meter to pixels.  You don't want to have a 1-1 ratio because each pixel would be a meter high from the physics engine's stand point and that might make your game behave oddy.

I use a PTM_RATIO of 16 and that seems to work in a lot of cases, so give that a try.

Just make sure you convert from the internal Box2D coordinate to your screen coordinates using the PTM_RATIO multiplier when you draw/position sprites/graphics and everything should come out fine and be as close to pixel perfect as a physics engine can be.